# Почему зомби может ломать объекты только вне дома в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему зомби может ломать объекты только вне дома в Unity? Тоесть если я поставлю объект на улице то зомби увидив его будет его ломать, но если я это сделаю дома то он не будет ломать и даже не замечает его.

Код:

```
void Attack()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(hip.transform.position, -hip.transform.up, out hit, 0.9f, layermask))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.tag);

        if (hit.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Player player))
        {
            if (agent.isOnNavMesh) stop = true;

            anim.SetBool("Run", false);
            anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);

            anim.SetBool("Attack", true);

            if (runner) player.TakeDamage(1);
            else player.TakeDamage(1);

            if (!attack.isPlaying) attack.Play();
        }

        if (hit.collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Building building))
        {
            if (agent.isOnNavMesh) stop = true;

            anim.SetBool("Run", false);
            anim.SetBool("Idle", false);
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);

            anim.SetBool("Attack", true);

            if (runner) building.TakeDamage(60);
            else building.TakeDamage(40);

            if (!attack.isPlaying) attack.Play();
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Debug.Log("1");

        if (agent.isOnNavMesh) stop = false;

        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        if (attack.isPlaying) attack.Stop();
    }
}
```

Игрока он дома и на улице атакует.

Comment: хочешь чтобы мы тебе всем селом код дебажили вместо тебя?